# CSAA/MSAA and specular lights

Tags: opengl, glsl, msaa

I have implemented support for MSAA in some variations:

It can use either context based (by calling wglChoosePixelFormatARB when setting up the context and passing an according parameter list to it) or by enabling MSAA rendering to FBO (creating a multisampling FBO with a color and depth renderbuffer attachment, and another FBO with color attachment for resolving), and the anti-aliasing seems to work in overall.

However I found some artefacts which seem to be related to specular lighting when I enable anti-aliasing. It is worst for context-based CSAA, and quite bad for context-based MSAA, but much better when I use MSAA when rendering to my FBO.

For one of the airplane models I use for testing it is very noticable, esp around the engine cylinders and some of the "wires" (they are actually not lines, but thin cylinders):

[image: result comparison]

As you can see on the image, when I turn off specular lights the problem is pretty much gone, but I am not quite sure what is causing it.

The above images use this shader code for calculating specular reflection (inside a loop for all the lights):

```
if( matShininess > 0.0 )
{
    vec3 reflectionCamSpace = reflect(-lightDirectionCamSpace, faceNormal);
    vec3 surfToViewerCamSpace = normalize (-vertPositionCamSpace);
    float dotSpecular = max( 0.0, dot (reflectionCamSpace, surfToViewerCamSpace) );
    float specularFactor = pow( dotSpecular, matShininess );
    specularTerm += vec3(lgt.specular * specularFactor); 
}
```

Also there seems to be quite a difference between different lighting models:

[image: lighting models]

The left side is using the above mentioned code for specular highlights, whereas the right side is using this (again inside the main light loop, which iterates through all the lights)

```
if( matShininess > 0.0 )
{
    vec3 surfToViewerCamSpace = normalize (-vertPositionCamSpace);
    vec3 halfAngle = normalize(lightDirectionCamSpace + surfToViewerCamSpace);
    float specularFactor = dot(faceNormal, halfAngle);
    specularFactor = clamp(specularFactor, 0, 1);
    specularFactor = lightDot != 0.0 ? specularFactor : 0.0;
    specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, matShininess);
    specularTerm += vec3(lgt.specular * specularFactor);
}
```

So I am wondering why is there such a big difference when using the FBO based MSAA and the context based one. And also what did I do wrong with my specular highlights to create the problem in the first place?

**Edit:** As requested by the post below I also added a test for comparing the result of 16xQ CSAA through context and through FBO (for FBO I am just using RenderbufferStorageMultisampleCoverageNV instead of glRenderbufferStorageMultisample). Again the FBO result seems better (but still not convincing):

[image: 16xQ CSAA Ctx vs FBO]

Comment: Hi, your images' links are broken, may you fix them? I am interested to take a look :)

Comment: Hi there, I just went looking for the images on my HDD... I remembered I uploaded them to my AWS before, but seems they got deleted when I did some cleanup a while back, and I couldn't find them anymore on my HDD either :( Also as it's been quite a while now, I can't remember if I already did anything to fix it or not... Have to go back to that project to check how it is looking now (sorry, seems I wiped my brain memory when I moved to another project lol)

Comment: lol, ok never mind, I dont wanna bore you too much :) Anyway, I'd appreciate if you could write some sum up about the anti-aliasing techniques you implemented

Comment: Oh I did manage to find those pics again (just not where I expected them lol)... so I uploaded them again, ie should work fine again

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer; more like a lengthy request for comments.*

[Sample shading](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sample_shading.txt) might help, you can tell the GL to evaluate the shader multiple times instead of doing the calculations once-per fragment and carrying over the results to all samples if coverage allows this optimization. With MSAA the shader is only evaluated once for a fragment whose primitive completely covers a pixel. The depth/stencil samples are unique per-sample and this helps with edge aliasing, but any aliasing that occurs within the shader itself (e.g. texture aliasing, specular highlights, etc.) is not rectified using pure MSAA.

Sample shading effectively turns MSAA into something between MSAA (multiple samples may be shaded once) to SSAA (1:1 sample:shading ratio). Why your issue only shows up using the MSAA resolve performed by the default framebuffer, I could not say. But sample shading should help.

As for CSAA, that is completely outside the realm of things that unextended GL has any control over. There is no notion of CSAA anywhere in the vanilla GL pipeline. Though you can implement it using an FBO if you use NV's [`NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/framebuffer_multisample_coverage.txt) extension.

To be honest, I would almost always give preference to FBO-based anti-aliasing these days. You do not have to re-create your render context for the end-user to change AA settings if you do this, which means a lot less resource re-loading if the user starts experimenting with configuration settings for performance/image quality. It is a much more flexible design, and you can even do MSAA deferred shading using FBOs on modern hardware thanks to multisample texture fetches (you can implement the resolve at the shader-level).

*I would be curious to know if you experienced any differences between context-based and FBO-based CSAA or if explicitly setting the minimum number of shading samples has any affect.*

Comment: @andon-m-coleman Please see the edit of my post above, I have added support for CSAA through FBO with the extension you mentioned. Again the results seem better in FBO (right side of the image) than through context (on the left)

Comment: P.S I will read up on sample shading etc later, thanks for the tip, but first I want to figure out where I am currently going wrong and why my specular lighting is causing those problems